# .NET web application - how to find logged in user's database records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

In my .NET CRUD web application I implemented MembershipProvider class.

Now I have function that lists records from database (this controller requires authenticated user). I need to filter out these records with respect to this logged-in user.

```
 //
        // GET: /Library/
        public ViewResult Index(String orderBy = "")
        {
            var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Category).Include(b => b.Writer).Include(b => b.User);

            return View(books.ToList());

        }
```

I need to know how to get logged in user's UserId and use it in Where condition (every tutorial I found talks about getting username but I need UserId). Thank you in advance.

Data I store in `*.mdf` data file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is:

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

The type of this is object, but if you are using the out of the box membership, it should be a guid.  This can then be used to filter your select accordingly.

---

Membership is part of the built in Membership Provider with a number of static methods.

Without knowing your DB structure/ORM, I can't exactly say, but it will be something like:

```
Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

var books = db.Books.Where(b => b.UserId == userId);
```

Comment: I am very beginner in .NET web application. Please could you be more specific? Membership is instance of my MemberShip provider? How to use this object for filtering?